# Kendo Grid - How do I compute a grid cell value based on other grid cell values

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid which receives data from an MVC controller.  The grid displays correctly and 1 of the columns is editable.  This is what the grid looks like when it is first rendered:

[image]

The Reduction column is an editable column.  I need to allow the user to enter a value in a cell in the Reduction column and based on the value entered, compute the Final Assessment as being the Orig Assessment - the value the user entered.

This is what the kendo grid code looks like:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TaxCertApp.ViewModels.SettlementMemoViewModel>()
   .Name("SettlementMemodGrid")
   .Columns(columns =>
   {
       columns.Bound(nr => nr.TaxYear).Width(50).Title("Tax Year");
       columns.Bound(nr => nr.OriginalAssessment).Width(100).Title("ORIG. ASSESSMENT").Format("{0:##########0}");
       columns.Bound(nr => nr.Reduction).Width(100).Title("REDUCTION").EditorTemplateName("Integer");
       columns.Bound(nr => nr.FinalAssessment).Width(100).Title("FINAL ASSESSMENT").Format("{0:###,###,##0}");
       columns.Bound(nr => nr.Rate).Width(100).Title("RATE").EditorTemplateName("Currency");
       columns.Bound(nr=> nr.RefundSavings).Width(100).Title("REFUND/SAVINGS").Format("{0:###,###,##0}");
       columns.Bound(e => e.Type).Width(100).EditorTemplateName("TypeList").Title("TYPE (R S R/S)");
   })
   .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
   .Pageable()
   .Scrollable()
   .Events(e => e.Edit("OnEdit"))
   .Events(ev => ev.Change("OnChange"))
   .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
   .Ajax()
   .Batch(true)
   .ServerOperation(false)
   .Model(model =>
   {
       model.Id(n => n.TaxYear);
       model.Field(n => n.OriginalAssessment).Editable(false);
       model.Field(n => n.Reduction).Editable(true);
       model.Field(n => n.FinalAssessment).Editable(false);
       model.Field(n => n.Rate).Editable(true);
       model.Field(n => n.RefundSavings).Editable(true);
       model.Field(n => n.Type).Editable(true);
   })
   .PageSize(20)
   .Read(read => { read.Action("SettlementMemoFetchGrid", "Forms").Data("BuildObjectGridSettMemo"); })
   )
```

)

When I click in a cell in the Reduction column, the javascript function OnEdit gets called, but its called before any editing is done to the value in the column.  The javascript function OnChange never gets executed.

How can I click in a cell in the Reduction column, enter a value, tab off the column, and have the value in Final Assessment get computed and displayed in the grid?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The change event only fires if the grid is selectable:
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/change

For the MVC server wrappers I imagine it would be something like this.

```
.Selectable(selectable => selectable
    .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Row)
    .Type(GridSelectionType.Cell))
```

https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/api/kendo.mvc.ui.fluent/gridbuilder

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I inserted the code you suggested.  I had to change the .Mode from GridSelectionMode.Row to GridSelectionMode.Single.  With the selectable in the grid definition, as soon as I click in the grid cell, both onChange and onEdit events fire.  Even if I dont type anything into the cell.  If I enter data into the cell and then either hit the enter key or tab out of the cell, neither onChange nor onEdit events fire.